# As String class is the subclass of Object class how the return type of toString() method in the Object class is String

Tags: java

Object is inherited by String 
So how String is made available in Object class as return type of toString() method

Comment: [Linking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.3) of classes and [initialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) of classes are separate steps.  You may find the code examples in the latter link informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inheritance relationship between `Object` and `String` does not prevent `Object` from knowing about `String`.

`String` just tells you the type that this method returns.

Comment: Then which class is made first String or Object

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance does not mean that the base class cannot have objects of child classes, if that's what you're thinking.

Inheritance does not really influence what objects can be created in a superclass or subclass.

Comment: Then which class is made first String or Object

Comment: Object was made first, String inherits from it (and so do all other classes in Java).

Comment: Thank You So much